# Easiest way to check if connection has been made to the server

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-2010

Currently I'm using a pretty weird and inefficient way to check if the database has made a connection to the server.

If you really want to know, I'm currently using this in an Add button.

```
if (listBox.SelectedIndex < 1)
{
    textBox1.Text = "Cannot connect to server";
}
```

Basically if you attempt to add something, and the listbox still remains empty the only thing that could explain that would be for the application to not be connected to the database.

Of course though, this only shows if you aren't connected until you attempt to add something, so pretty ineffective.

Is there a method of some sort that can check the connection instantly in one class, then allow you to display an error message in a textBox in another class?

Answer (score 0):

well I pretty much just made a Public static variable in one class. After the database connected in a method on startup, it set the variable to xxx. If the method got to the Catch, it would set it to yyy. In the Form class I just set the textBox to display that variable.

Comment: please note that being connected now does not necessarily mean being connected in the future. And there might be reasons to get to the Catch that don't mean that the database is inaccessible, but more like no data or an error while executing your code.